# Does Ubuntu 12.04 LTS support booting from RAID 6?

Tags: lvm, software-raid, ubuntu-12.04, grub

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu server using 12.04.2 LTS. I have five drives that I am setting up in a RAID 6 with LVM. Can I use this for bootup? Or should I make a separate RAID 1 partition for bootup (grub)?

Answer (score 0):

GRUB2 can boot from LVM+RAID5, so I'd guess that it can also boot from RAID6.